# How to ng-hide login button after successful login Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have started sideMenu app in ionic and tried some implementation. Initially, ionicModal is used to show login so i change it with ion-list item like;

```
<ion-side-menu side="left" >
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable  bar-dark">
      <a ng-click="redirectToWeb()" > <h1 class="title">NerdApp</h1></a>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content >
      <ion-list  class="BGcolorDG">
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close class="BGcolorDG item item-icon-left item-content-modified" href="#/app/login" ng-show="control.showLogin" > <!--ng-click="login()" -->
          <i class="icon ion-locked"></i> <span>Login</span>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/search" class="item item-icon-left BGcolorDG item-content-modified">
            <i class="icon ion-search"></i><span>Search</span>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/browse" class="item item-icon-left BGcolorDG item-content-modified">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-browsers"></i><span>Browse</span>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/playlists" class="item item-icon-left BGcolorDG item-content-modified">
            <i class="icon ion-music-note"></i> <span>Playlists</span>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
```

and provide routeState as

```
state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
  controller: 'AppCtrl'
})
.state('app.login', {
      url: "/login",
      views: {
          'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
              controller: "LoginCtrl"
          }
      }
  })
.state('app.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
          'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
              controller: "HomeCtrl"
          }
      }
})
```

And default route to home controller.

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
```

the app controller is as

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$timeout,$location,$rootScope) {
         $scope.control = {
            showLogin:true
        };

        if($rootScope.showLogin != undefined && $rootScope.showLogin == false){
            $scope.control.showLogin = false;
        }           
})
```

Inside loginControl i am checking and redirecting it back to home controller as

```
$scope.login = function() {
            if ($scope.loginData.username == 'hassaan' && $scope.loginData.password == 'khan') {
                $rootScope.showLogin = false;
              //  $location.path('#/app');
                $state.go('app.home');
            }else{
            alert('Incorrect credentials');
            }
        }
```

i have tried both $location.path and $state.go and what its doing is redirecting to home page but 'not showing the sidemenu' and when i inspect in browser it showing sidemenu hidden.

The flow images of test app is as

[image: Initial View]

[image: Side Menu Showing]
[image: Login]
[image: After login sidemenu hiding]

Answer (score 1):

Try use $rootScope
pass it to AppCtrl

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function (...., $rootScope) {
        // and then 
        $rootScope.control = {
            showProfile: false
        };
```

after success authentication - make it true

```
$rootScope.control = {
    showProfile: true
};
```

now it should work as you expected

Answer (score 0):

Don't use $rootscop if you dont need to.
You can send variables to other controllers with the router from angular using params.

```
.state('menu.employeeInfo', {
      url: '/employeeInfo',
      views: {
          'side-menu21': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/employeeInfo.html',
              controller: 'employeeInfoCtrl'              
          }
      },
      params: {
          appointmentObj: null,
          subassignmentObj: null
      }
  })
```

You can then pass these vars in the following manner.

```
$scope.gotoAppointment = function (Appointment, Subassignment) {
            $state.go('menu.employeeInfo', { appointmentObj: Appointment, subassignmentObj: Subassignment }, { reload: true });
        }
```